# How to show layers with multiple filters on OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, filter, vector-layer

**UPDATE 17 NOV 22** + **FURTHER CLARIFICATIONS**

I add some more info to my question below.

The vector layers are coming from geojson files that appears like the following

```
 {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "ISRA_examples",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { 
"Status": "ISRA",
"Region": "Central and South America Pacific", 
"Countries": "El Salvador", 
"Order": "SQUALIFORMES", 
"Family": "Squalidae, Somniosidae, Arhynchobatidae", 
"Species": "<em>Squalus acanthias<\/em>, <em>Squalus mitsukurii<\/em>, <em>Zameus squamulosus<\/em>, <em>Bathyraja fedorovi<\/em>, <em>Notoraja sticta<\/em>, <em>Rhinoraja kujiensis<\/em>"
}, 
"geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -112.416034535675877, 29.377821790373176 ], .... ] ] ] ] } },

//it goes on like that, each polygon having different terms for each feature
]
}
```

Each geojson file corresponds to a world region (so I have 1 file per each region. They are grouped in a array named `layers_group[]` and their source are also grouped in another array `source_group[]`.

I have a created filter in which I can select the features in order to show only those areas that match the selected filters (with the function feat.setStyle to apply transparency or color to the selected features).

Any kind of selection I pick up from the filters is visualized on the map. Either I filter by country only (or region or species etc.), or I filter by 2 different parameters (e.g. region(s) + species, or country(ies) + family etc.).
No problem for that: the code below is already doing it.

My problem is the following. In case I have the following output from my filter

```
var country_selected = Array [ "Chile", "Mexico" ]

var checked_species = Array [ "Carcharhinus plumbeus" ]
```

the areas that are visualized with the code I wrote below will be:

- Areas with Mexico as country feature
- Areas with Chile as country
  feature
- Areas with Charcharhinus plumbeus as species feature -> these may be also areas from other countries (not only Chile and Mexico), that anyway contain the word  Charcharhinus plumbeus in the species feature.

Instead, I would like to being able to visualize the areas containing the selected species (or family or orders), only within the countries that where selected.

**PRESENT FUNCTION**

```
(function($) {
    
    document.getElementById('submit_filters').onclick = function() {
        var checked_region = document.querySelectorAll('#region_filter :checked');
        var region_selected = [...checked_region].map(option => option.value);
        var checked_countries = document.querySelectorAll('#country_filter :checked');
        var country_selected = [...checked_countries].map(option => option.value);
        var checked_status = document.querySelectorAll('#isra_filter :checked');
        var status_selected = [...checked_status].map(option => option.value);
        var checked_region = document.querySelectorAll('#region_filter :checked');
        var region_selected = [...checked_region].map(option => option.value);
        var checked_countries = document.querySelectorAll('#country_filter :checked');
        var country_selected = [...checked_countries].map(option => option.value);
        var checked_areas = document.querySelectorAll('#isra_filter :checked');
        var areas_selected = [...checked_areas].map(option => option.value);        
        var checked_order = document.querySelectorAll('#order_filter :checked');
        var order_selected = [...checked_order].map(option => option.value);
        var checked_family = document.querySelectorAll('#family_filter :checked');
        var family_selected = [...checked_family].map(option => option.value);
        var checked_species = document.querySelectorAll('#species_filter :checked');

                        //We pass the array of selected variables, in order to match each one with the source

                       //regions
                        if(region_selected.length !== 0) {
                            for (k = 0; k < region_selected.length; ++k){
                                var feature_sel = region_selected[k];
                                //if "all" 
                                if (feature_sel == "all"){
                                    for (j = 0; j < layers_group.length; ++j){
                                        layers_group[j].setVisible(true);
                                    };
                                    for (index = 0; index < source_group.length; ++index){
                                        source_group[index].forEachFeature(function(feat){
                                            if (feat.get('Status') == "cISRA") {
                                                feat.setStyle(cIsraStyle);
                                            } else if (feat.get('Status') == "ISRA") {
                                                feat.setStyle(defaultStyle);
                                            }
                                            else if (feat.get('Status') == "AoI") {
                                                feat.setStyle(aoiStyle);
                                            }
                                        })
                                    };   
                                }
                                //else pass the specific term(s)
                                else {
                                    for (index = 0; index < source_group.length; ++index){
                                        source_group[index].forEachFeature(function(feat){
                                            let regions = feat.get('Region');
                                            if(regions.indexOf(feature_sel)!=-1) {
                                                for (j = 0; j < layers_group.length; ++j){
                                                    layers_group[j].setVisible(true);
                                                };                                              
                                                if (feat.get('Status') == "cISRA") {        
                                                    feat.setStyle(cIsraStyle);
                                                } else if (feat.get('Status') == "ISRA") {
                                                    feat.setStyle(defaultStyle);
                                                }
                                                else if (feat.get('Status') == "AoI") {
                                                    feat.setStyle(aoiStyle);
                                                }
                                            }                                           
                                        })
                                    };
                                }                                
                            };
                        }

                        //countries
                        if(country_selected.length !== 0) {
                            for (k = 0; k < country_selected.length; ++k){
                                var feature_sel = country_selected[k];
                                    if (feature_sel == "all"){
                                        for (j = 0; j < layers_group.length; ++j){
                                            layers_group[j].setVisible(true);
                                        };
                                        for (index = 0; index < source_group.length; ++index){
                                            source_group[index].forEachFeature(function(feat){
                                                if (feat.get('Status') == "cISRA") {
                                                    feat.setStyle(cIsraStyle);
                                                } else if (feat.get('Status') == "ISRA") {
                                                    feat.setStyle(defaultStyle);
                                                }
                                                else if (feat.get('Status') == "AoI") {
                                                    feat.setStyle(aoiStyle);
                                                }
                                            })
                                        };   
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        for (index = 0; index < source_group.length; ++index){                                           
                                            source_group[index].forEachFeature(function(feat){                                                
                                                let countries = feat.get('Countries');                                               
                                                if(countries.indexOf(feature_sel)!=-1) {                                                   
                                                    for (j = 0; j < layers_group.length; ++j){
                                                        layers_group[j].setVisible(true);
                                                    };                                              
                                                    if (feat.get('Status') == "cISRA") {        
                                                        feat.setStyle(cIsraStyle);
                                                    } else if (feat.get('Status') == "ISRA") {
                                                        feat.setStyle(defaultStyle);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (feat.get('Status') == "AoI") {
                                                        feat.setStyle(aoiStyle);
                                                    }                                                    
                                                }                                        
                                            })
                                        };   
                                    }
                            };
                        }
// ..... it goes on like that passing all the filters
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: On first sight there seems to be discrepancy between comments and actual code. Comment says `//First of all we set layers transparent and not visible to reset the view`, but actual code sets layers to visible: `layers_group[j].setVisible(true)`.

Comment: Given the nature of geojson files (each file corresponds to a region and within each region I have different polygons with a series of features such as "region name", country name" species name" etc.) I set the layers visible, but with a transparent style. Following the filters, features are given a certain style (with different colors fill) so that I can see only those polygons that meet the conditions given in the filter

Comment: It's then just not clear why you are explicitly setting layers visible, since they are nowhere in the above code set as not visible.

Comment: Yes you are right, since I forgot it sets the layers visible later on. So I put the `layers_group[j].setVisible(false)`, but still it doesn't work. I though did a step forward by joining the `array_Filters` in one single array `feature_selected = array_Filters.flat();` so I can pass one by one the options selected. Still I don't find the proper argument to apply the function `indexOf()` on different features contemporarily

Comment: Logic of what is shown upon various combinations of selections is not clear. I suppose it goes like so: if only region and/or country is selected, but no order, family or species is selected, nothing is shown. For something to be shown, at least one of order, family or species has to be selected. If no country or region is selected, order, family or species are shown for all countries and regions. If countries and/or regions are selected, order, family or species are shown for selected countries and regions. Please edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question trying to be clearer.

Comment: So if you only select a country and nothing else, what is is shown then? All species for that country?

Comment: If I select one single country (for example Chile) I will visualize all the polygons with "Chile" in the geojson feature named "Country". These areas (polygons) may have very different species listed in the feature named "Species" (and accordingly different families and orders). I have a test published (many functions still in progress) at this address https://sharkrayareas.org/test-map/

Comment: One more question. What if both region and country are selected and: (a) country is in selected region (b) country is not in selected region?

Comment: In that case all the areas corresponding to the region selected and the areas corresponding to the country (not in the region) should be visualized (this is actually happening with my code above), because they will be always 2 independent terms (I may want to give a look to the areas corresponding to a region + to an additional country) .

Comment: While in the example I posted, if  I search for a specific species (or order, or family)  in a certain place (country or region), I don't need to know where the same species is elsewhere, but only in that determined geographical area. 
Actually in the link I gave, you may see that there even more parameters to filter (for example those named "Criteria" or "Subcriteria" and "Depth". These should be handled in the same way of species/order/family.

Comment: And one more question. I see that regions and countries have also selector `"all"`. What if no country or region is selected? Does this imply `"all"` selection?

Comment: Well as the work is in progress I am still not sure to include the "all" possibility.... at least not for each parameter. Probably only for regions  and "area names" (which in the online example are still empty => these will correspond to the title of each polyfon). The "all" option should help to have a full vision of all polygons with just one click without reloading the page.

Comment: Just to give you an idea of how these layers are used: polygons are areas that represent a conservation tool. these areas are identified on biological/ecological evidence, that means based on the presence of certain species, on a series of criteria and subcriteria that define the importance of these species have for a single area, and the species habitat (depth). Each polygon has a name (title) and is attributed to a Region and to a Country. The filter should help people selecting the areas on the basis of these parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution below is based on the following understanding of feature display on the basis of criteria selection:

- if no country or region is selected, features are displayed for all selected orders, families and species;
- if countries and/or regions are selected, features are displayed for all selected orders, families and species in those countries/regions;
- if countries and/or regions are selected, but no order, family or species is selected, all features for those countries/regions are displayed.

Basic idea is to iterate over all features only once and check all conditions for each feature. If conditions for display are not met, feature style is set to `hiddenStyle` which prevents display. There is no layer hiding/displaying.

Code could then look something like this (not tested):

```
var hiddenStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  zIndex: 0
});

for (var i = 0; i < source_group.length; i++) {
  var selected, region_OK, country_OK, style;
  source_group[i].forEachFeature(function(feature){
    var selected = false;
    var region_OK = (region_selected.length == 0);
    var country_OK = (country_selected.length == 0);
    if (species_selected.indexOf(feature.get('Species')) >= 0) selected = true;
    if (family_selected.indexOf(feature.get('Family')) >= 0) selected = true;
    if (order_selected.indexOf(feature.get('Order')) >= 0) selected = true;
    if ((country_selected.length > 0) && (country_selected.indexOf(feature.get('Countries')) < 0)) country_OK = false;
    if ((region_selected.length > 0) && (country_selected.indexOf(feature.get('Region')) < 0)) region_OK = false;
    if (!(country_OK || region_OK)) selected = false;
    if (!selected)
      style = hiddenStyle;
    else {
      if (feat.get('Status') == "cISRA")
        style = cIsraStyle;
      else if (feat.get('Status') == "ISRA")
        style = defaultStyle;
      else if (feat.get('Status') == "AoI") {
        style = aoiStyle;
      }
    }
    feat.setStyle(style);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @TomazicM. The code doesn't work as it is, but I understand the logic and I will work on it. I am sure I will solve the problem with your suggestions.